# Blender Viewport not updating via python script even if geometry node parameter is changed via script

Tags: python, blender

I have created a geometry node setup in blender 3.5 named "Cube transform", and I want to update the parameter of the geometry Node input using python script, the value is getting updated but the viewPort is not updating automatically. I have used line `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` to update the viewport but it seems to not working incase of geometry node but working fine in case of other inbuilt modifiers.

```
import bpy

bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_set_active(modifier="Cube transform")
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Cube tranform"]["Input_2"] = 10
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

geoNode input

[image]

Node setup

[image]

Comment: it's impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the object in 3D viewport using:

```
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
cube.modifiers.update()
cube.update_tag()
```